# DevTools do not find node process after click 'Open Dedicate for Node'

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, devtools

Chrome devtools does not find node process to debug.

If I click to inspect, the node process is found and I can debug, but if I click open dedicate devtools for node, node process is not found and I can not use debbuger, devtools not find automatically and don't open debug window.

[image]

[image]

[image]